# How to rebuild dockerfile quick by using cache?

Tags: caching, centos, docker

I want to optimize my Dockerfile. And I wish to keep cache file in disk.
But, I found when I run `docker build .` It always try to get every file from network.

I wish to share My cached directory during build (eg. /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6).
But, it works only on `docker run -v ...`.

Any suggestion?(In this example, only 1 rpm installed, in real case, I require to install hundreds rpms)

My draft Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.4
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN sed -i -e 's:keepcache=0:keepcache=1:' /etc/yum.conf
VOLUME ["/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6"] 
EXPOSE 22
```

At second time, I want to build a similar image

```
FROM centos:6.4
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y openssh-server vim
```

I don't want the fetch openssh-server from internat again(It is slow). In my real case, it is not one package, it is about 100 packages.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand the question correctly: if you run that Dockerfile twice, the second time will go very fast, right? If it doesn't, you probably have an issue with your Docker setup, because that should work just fine. However, if your issue is about "how to I build multiple Dockerfiles and have a common yum/apt cache", then it's a different story :-)

Comment: The question as posed is CentOS specific, but for readers using Debian and derivatives, see https://docs.docker.com/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

Comment: You can do a common base image, and use it FROM mybaseimage, but I believe you are speaking about a cache proxy, thats another story (such as an apt-cacher, or aggressive proxy cache), or you could download all packages before and ADD them when building Dockerfile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An update to previous answers, current docker [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)
 accepts `--build-arg` that pass environment variables like `http_proxy`
 without saving it in the resulting image.

Example:

```bash
# get squid
docker run --name squid -d --restart=always \
  --publish 3128:3128 \
  --volume /var/spool/squid3 \
  sameersbn/squid:3.3.8-11

# optionally in another terminal run tail on logs
docker exec -it squid tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log

# get squid ip to use in docker build
SQUID_IP=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' squid)

# build your instance
docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://$SQUID_IP:3128 .
```

Comment: This solution sounds great, but it fails to cache the large tarball (http://master.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.0/submodules/qtbase-everywhere-src-5.12.0.tar.xz, 48289352 bytes) that I want it to cache. Every time docker runs `curl`, the squid logs say TCP_MISS/200 and a real download happens. Is there a max file size in squid's configuration that I need to tweak maybe?

Comment: Found it: https://serverfault.com/questions/596890/squid3-not-caching-larger-files explains what to use as config file for squid (with the gotcha that `maximum_object_size` should be before `cache_dir`), and then one can make docker use that local config file by passing `--volume $PWD/squid.conf:/etc/squid3/squid.conf` in the `docker run` command. Strange default values from squid...

Answer (score 11):

Just use an intermediate/base image:

Base Dockerfile, build it with `docker build -t custom-base` or something:

```
FROM centos:6.4
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y openssh-server vim
RUN sed -i -e 's:keepcache=0:keepcache=1:' /etc/yum.conf
```

Application Dockerfile:

```
FROM custom-base
VOLUME ["/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6"] 
EXPOSE 22
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use a caching proxy (f.e [Http Replicator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/http-replicator/), squid-deb-proxy ...) or apt-cacher-ng for Ubuntu to cache installation packages. I think, you can install this software to the host machine.

### EDIT:

**Option 1 - caching http proxy - easier method with modified Dockerfile:**

```
> cd ~/your-project
> git clone https://github.com/gertjanvanzwieten/replicator.git
> mkdir cache
> replicator/http-replicator -r ./cache -p 8080 --daemon ./cache/replicator.log  --static
```

add to your Dockerfile (before first RUN line):

```
ENV http_proxy http://172.17.42.1:8080/
```

You should optionally clear the cache from time to time.

**Option 2 - caching transparent proxy, no modification to Dockerfile:**

```
> cd ~/your-project
> curl -o r.zip https://codeload.github.com/zahradil/replicator/zip/transparent-requests
> unzip r.zip
> rm r.zip
> mv replicator-transparent-requests replicator
> mkdir cache
> replicator/http-replicator -r ./cache -p 8080 --daemon ./cache/replicator.log --static
```

You need to start the replicator as some user (non root!).

Set up the transparent redirect:

```
> iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner <replicator-user> --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Disable redirect:

```
> iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner <replicator-user> --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This method is the most transparent and general and your Dockerfile does not need to be modified. You should optionally clear the cache from time to time.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want, but, because the release image will be used by others. So, setup proxy settings inside docker image seems is not perfect solution.