# docker build fabric starter kit(npm error)

Tags: hyperledger

I was building HyperLedger fabric starter kit in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit with the [guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starter/fabric-starter-kit/) and got this npm error:

[image]

Anyone knows what's wrong ?

Comment: take a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193614/npm-err-network-getaddrinfo-enotfound).

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this error because you are probably trying to run `docker build` behind a corporate proxy.

To force docker to use the proxy server for the build, you can specify the http-proxy and https-proxy settings as [build-args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

```
 docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=<http proxy url> HTTPS_PROXY=<https proxy url>
```

Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749193/how-to-build-docker-images-with-dockerfile-behind-http-proxy-by-jenkins), which addresses a similar problem