# docker: how-to install elasticsearch delete-by-query

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, elasticsearch-plugin

On a server with no internet connectivity, usually am installing packages using a proxy (tiny proxy on port 8888) by just doing `export`

How can i possibly install the `delete-by-query` plugin inside a docker container ?

If i do `--publish 8888:8888` and `export` port 8888 in both host+container, i do not succeed on having internet connectivity inside the container (on host i can establish internet connectivity)

Can you please advise on how-to circumvent this ?
am using the official elasticsearch docker image.

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Comment: The delete-by-query plugin has been removed in favor of a new Delete By Query API implementation in core.  ES 7.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environments (ENV) in `Dockerfiles`

```
ENV http_proxy tiny_proxy:8888
ENV https_proxy tiny_proxy:8888
```

So when build the image, the build process will download plugin or other patches (such as `yum update`) from Internet via proxy servers you defined in `Dockerfile`

Comment: also, can it be done without restarting the container ?

Comment: Not get your question. Docker image is a read-only layer, you need get the plugin installed when build it. But you shouldn't think to install the plugin in container, which running from docker image. Container is the writable-layer running on the image.

Comment: and export is not Docker way to set environment. Using `ENV`

Comment: oh thanks. let me try to build a new image with the plugin in question. and will confirm.

Comment: Take a look on this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179301/how-do-you-run-apt-get-in-a-dockerfile-behind-a-proxy