# Getting Internet connection inside Docker containers inside an VM behind a corporate firewall

Tags: docker

Heya :) I have a problem, that I hope some of you have already encountered. I'm running Docker inside a Ubuntu 12 VM sitting behind a corporate firewall using `ssh -R 3128:webcache:3128 fooVM` to login. Pulling and pushing images works just fine, so I suspected the daemon knows everything it needs to. However when I try to run a command inside an container that needs internet access it basically freezes (e.g. while building).

http(s) proxy environment variables on the host are set properly. I have tried various things so far, all of them have failed: using `ENV http(s)_proxy http://localhost:3128` to hard bake the proxy settings into container, putting the proxy into /etc/default/docker, running the jpetazzo's [squid in a can](https://github.com/jpetazzo/squid-in-a-can).

Strangely when I try to ping from inside the container it always resolves the URL into the right IP. So the DNS is working correctly?

Still being a student, this pushes my networking knowledge to its boundaries. Probably either solution would work if done correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers! :)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030931/how-to-rebuild-dockerfile-quick-by-using-cache/22089946#22089946, `ENV http_proxy http://172.17.42.1:3128/` seems to be what you are after

Comment: @Thomasleveil Thanks for the input! Unfortunately this approach did not work. It seems pretty similar to running a squid cache, which I tried before. I'm pretty sure I am overlooking something here :/