# How can I save docker container state during builds?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm building a docker image that does a lot of `apt-get installs` and when one fails the container build errors and after fixing the Dockerfile `docker build -t tag .` will still download dependencies that were successfully installed in the first build. How can I make `docker build` to continue where it left off?

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is using separate Dockerfiles. Then you can simply use the `--cache-from` flag, [per the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build), to use the base image as cache.

See also: [How to rebuild dockerfile quick by using cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22030931/8507637)

Answer (score 0):

Docker will run whole `RUN` commands, and caching is at that level.  Usually it's beneficial to have just one `RUN apt-get install` line, but there's nothing actually wrong with breaking it up

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install package1 package2 package3
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install package4 package5 package6
```

Then if something fails downloading `package5`, re-running the `docker build` will start after the cached layer with the first three packages installed.

(If you're installing so many packages that this is routinely a problem, also consider whether you can reduce the scope of your container to something smaller that needs fewer initial downloads.)

Comment: Which command do I use to have docker use this cache because at the moment it doesn't. If the 9nth package fails to download and the build fails. A rerun still downloads the 8 packages that were already downloaded before. I'm installing dependencies for an open source software I want to work on so I can't split it into different containers. And I do have just RUN command but it's trying to install multiple packages.